# can neo4j coalesce identical object nodes?

Tags: neo4j

I am considering learning graph databases (like neo4j), but I was curious if such facilities are available in graph databases, eg., If I do:

```
Step 1: create:  A --> B --> C
Step 2: create:  D --> B --> E
Step 3: create:  F --> G --> E
```

This should **automatically** result in a graph stored something like:

```
A ---> B ----> C
      /|\  \ 
D -----|    \--> E
                /|\
F ---> G --------|
```

Here the common nodes B and E are coalesced (without having to programmatically check for a prior existence of these nodes).  In a real world example, there would be 1000's of such B's and E's which would be implemented in relational DB as follows:

```
FK = Foreign Key  .. X Y Z are keys for three primary tables. 

___________       ________    _____________    ________
X  | FK(Y)        Y | ...     FK(Y) | FK(Z)     Z | ..
---|-------       --|-----    ------|------    ---|----
A  | FK(B)        B | ...     FK(B) | FK(C)     C | ..
D  | FK(B)        G | ..      FK(B) | FK(E)     E | ..
F  | FK(G)                    FK(G) | FK(E)
```

In a RDB, (eg., when I insert relation D-->B) I would have to programmatically search for a duplicate object B in the 2nd table (or look for a fail code when trying to insert an identical object into it) and then get the B's foreign key to put along with D.  I am hoping that in graph DB, such things are taken care of by the DB.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should look at v2.0's new `MERGE` clause, which allows you to have a follow-on `ON MATCH` and `ON CREATE` clause, so you can take a specific action when a node is found vs created.

See the [2.0M3 blog post](http://blog.neo4j.org/2013/05/new-milestone-release-neo4j-200-m03.html) for an intro (2.0M4 is the latest build but MERGE was intro'd in M3), as well as this "What's new in 2.0" [video](http://player.vimeo.com/video/72069694).

Comment: Thanks a lot.  Will look at those features once I start to get a hang of it. But at least I now know that such things are possible without too much coding.

Comment: Keep in mind that the 2.0 milestones are not ready for production yet and some of the specifics of the new features are in flux (there may be breaking changes in the next milestone).  If you're stuck with 1.9.2 then there's a plugin someone made that does atomic upserts. I haven't used it yet.  https://github.com/trentonstrong/neo4j-atomic-create-update

Comment: Good point, @LameCoder. I figured that, since the OP was *"considering" learning graph databases*, focusing on the upcoming (yet not-yet-ready-for-production) v2.0 was fairly low risk.